# Angular 2 Routing based on query params

Tags: angular, routes

Is it possible in Angular 2 to define routing based on query parameters? 
I'd like to have the following behaviour:

If the user enteres the url `http:<server-path>/search` I'd like to route to a `StartPage` component.

If the user enteres the url `http:<server-path>/search?query=sometext` I'd like to route to `ResultList` component.

I know that it's possible to use *path* parameters for routing but this is not what I like to do. I want to use *query* parameters if possible.
I know how to trigger navigation in angular with query parameters but I don't know how to configure the Routes.

Answer (score 14):

So you can't define a `path` with the query string in it but you can use a route `matcher` instead and determine when to route to the `ResultList` component. You define this above the default route definition for `search` so that if the match fails it will default to the search route with no query string.

```js
{
    component: ResultListComponent,
    matcher: (url: UrlSegment[]) => {
      console.log(url);
      return url.length === 1 && url[0].path.indexOf('search?query=') > -1 ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
    }
},
{
    path: 'search',
    component: SearchComponent,
}
```

## [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/To7ZzrWUDJps58v7MdIs)

Comment: In your example you are not actually using query params but including "query=example" into path. The actual url after encoding is `/search%3Fquery%3Dexample` instead of `/search?query=example`. Thus, your answer does not answer the original question.

Comment: In Angular 5, no query strings arrive in the path property. Nevertheless, you could still utilize window.location.href as fallback. If there's no better idea...

Comment: @MarcoKlein I thought I was going crazy for a minute. Can't believe that's still true.

Answer (score 1):

In the below code I'll show how to pass query string parameters across any route.

suppose we want to have the below url:

```
http://localhost:4200/myUrl?QueryParamEx=2258
```

In your constructor inject the ROUTER dependency

```
constructor(...private router: Router..){...}
```

*The navigate function will allow us to navigate to the preceding url*

```
goMyUrl() {
  this.router.navigate(['/myUrl'], { queryParams: { QueryParamEx: '2258' } });
}
```