# Angular get query params

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I need to send next url to component:

`http://localhost:3000/interactive/malenkoe_obyavlenie?device_type=phone`

I tried next:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  RouterModule.forChild([
    {
      path: ':id?device_type',
      component: InteractivePreviewComponent
    }
  ]),
  CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [InteractivePreviewComponent]
})
```

but it's not works.
`path: ':id/:device_type*',` - in this case I have worked module but it brings another url format
`http://localhost:3000/interactive/malenkoe_obyavlenie/phone`

UPD: my goal is get 'queryParams'.

Comment: You don't base the *routing* on the query parameters, they're extra information you get from the activated route in the component. See e.g. https://angular.io/guide/router#activatedroute-the-one-stop-shop-for-route-information

Comment: In AngularJS this was pretty easy `$stateProvider
    .state('incidents-list', {
        url: '/incidents?page&perPage&on&state })` and I thought in Angular2 it must works too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Routing based on query params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299753/angular-2-routing-based-on-query-params)

Answer (score 0):

I found `queryParams` in different field of ActivatedRoute:

```
this.routeParamsSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
//get id from params  
if(params['id']) {
    this.slug = params['id']
    //subscribing to change queryParams 
    this.routeParamsSubscription = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        // get query params this!
        this.init(this.slug, params['device_type'])
    })
  }
})
```

Good tutorial about this topic:
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/query_params.html