# Angular route path with query param

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a route defined as:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MyComponent },
  { path: 'my-details', component: MyDetailsComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

So, when I navigate using a router like this:

```
const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = { queryParams: { myId: this.id } };
this.router.navigate(['/my-details'], navigationExtras);
```

it works and the URL is:

```
http://localhost:4200/my-details?myId=1
```

The problem is when I hit the refresh button, route table does not match the route and it navigates to the default one.

How can I define a route to match my refresh case?

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand what's the issue you were trying to explain.

Comment: navigating from code with queryparams works. but on pagereload with the queryparams inside the url, angular routes to the default route, which is ' ' (root path). This is what I understood

Comment: I Think in this question there is an answer, about a routematcher, this looks like its solving the problem. Its upvoted 9 times and from the user Teddy Sterne --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299753/angular-2-routing-based-on-query-params